exclamative (claust type) properties
My lecture notes state that exclamatives "cannot be answers to questions"
eg. Did you enjoy it? How I enjoyed it! (*)
How about clauses with 'such' and 'so' though? Are they only exclamatives if they appear at the front of the clause?
eg. Such an idiot! => clause type: exclamative, speech act: exclamation
but he was a such an idiot => clause type: declarative, speech act: exclamation

I don’t see anything wrong with “How I enjoyed it!” as an answer to “Did you enjoy it?” – it’s akin to answering, “Boy, did I ever!”. Not the most usual way to phrase such a reply, perhaps, but certainly not wrong either. I don’t understand what you mean by ‘lists’, though – I don’t see any lists in your question at all.

sorry, 'lists' was a typo; fixed it to 'that'

typo in title re clause Seems to be that most sentences can be made exclamative with punctuation (exclamation mark) that actually signals intonation. Your notes thing is not a hard-and-fast rule. But in terms of dialogue, it's often but not always true. Pers. 1: He didn't love the show? Pers. 2: No, he loved it!

@Amy Exclamative clauses do not themselves convey affirmative or negative responses, though exclamatory expressions (as opposed to exclamative clauses) may convey such meanings. Note that exclamative clauses are marked by an exclamative phrase containing "what" or "how". Your example "Such an idiot!" is therefore not an exclamative clause.
